# Adding L2 regularization to neuralnet()

Tags: r, neural-network

Is there any way, I can add simple L1/L2 regularization in the `neuralnet()` function in R? I'm aware that other packages in R such as `neuralnetwork()` offer regularization methods in the function, but I have a custom error function and `neuralnet()` allows this is contrast to many other neural network functions.

When I add a Frobenius norm to my error function by:

```
vError <- function(x,y, startweights){
0.01*frobenius.norm(startweights) + 0.9*(y-x) + 0.01*log(1+(exp(-(y- 
x)/0.01)))
}
```

and call this error function in `neuralnet()` by

```
err.fct= vError(x, y, nn$weights[[1]][[1]])
```

I receive the **error:**

> Error in .cbind.ts(list(e1, e2), c(deparse(substitute(e1))[1L], deparse(substitute(e2))[1L]),  : 
>     not all series have the same frequency
>   Solutions that don't require manual adjustments are preferred